# Sas grouping Strings

Tags: sas

I have a data set it includes nearly 6000 observations ,it looks like this

```
Id        mark
134663    000
134663    000
134663    000
134665    101
134665    111
134665    101
134973    000
134973    000
134973    100
```

mark on this data set is string ,which is generated by mark=mark1!!mark2!!mark3
what i want to do is grouping this dataset by id ,and mark should be the biggest one of it
.
at the end It should look like this

```
id      mark
134663  000
134665  111
134973  100
```

I tried different things but couldnt done it. I hope i made it clear. And if you guys could solve this that would be awesome
Thanks,

Comment: Is `mark` a character or numeric column?

Comment: Thanks, I assumed from how it was created that it would be, but it's best to clarify.  I would use the same method as @data _null_, which works providing the character length is the same for all records (3 in your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PROC SUMMARY IDGROUP to find the max of MARK for each ID.

```
data mark;
   input (id mark)(:$6. :$3.);
   cards;
134663    000
134663    000
134663    000
134665    101
134665    111
134665    101
134973    000
134973    000
134973    100
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=mark nway;
   class id;
   output out=maxmark(drop=_:) idgroup(max(mark) out(mark)=);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also try to use proc sql:

```
   proc sql;
      select distinct * from mark group by id having mark=max(mark);
   quit;
```